# MATLAB processamento de imagem

Tags: matlab, rgb

Como converter uma imagem em tons de cinzento (gray) para uma imagem em cores (rgb)?

```
img=im2double(imread('37_M.jpg'));
figure(1),
imshow(img,[]),
title('original');
t=imgaussfilt3(img,0.2);
figure(2),
imshow(t,[]),
title('original filtro');
img2=rgb2gray(t);
figure(3),
imshow(img2,[]),
title('original gray');
```

Eu quero uma imagem final que seja a junção da img com a img2 depois de segmentada e com contornos, mas como img é 3D e img2 2D não sei como fazer.

Comment: Adicione e sua pergunta algum código! matlab é um troço muito reservado e nem todos aqui conhecem esse programa!

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode converter imagens em tons de cinza de volta para rgb pois não tem informação suficiente. Muitas combinações diferentes de valores RGB convertem para o mesmo nível de tons de cinza, portanto, se tudo o que você tem é o nível de tons de cinza, então você não pode saber qual dos valores RGB que mapeiam exatamente a mesma escala de cinza que o RGB original.
No seu caso, você não precisa de uma imagem colorida, mas apenas uma imagem em tons de cinza com 3 canais (tal como o formato rgb). Assim, você precisa apenas de transformar a imagem em tons de cinzento (1 canal) no formato de 3 canais.

Para tal você pode usar:

```
img2 = cat(3,img2,img2,img2);
```

ou

```
img2 = repmat(img2,[1 1 3]);
```

Agora ambas as imagens im e im2 tem o mesmo formato (verifique usando size(img) e size(im2)).